# how to set MaxDate and MinDate to DatePicker returned from webservice on ios

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I have a an XML response  which returns the below data as response

```
Start Day of the Week-Wednesday
End Day of the Week-Sunday
Start time -16:00
End time -19:00
```

Now I know how to parse these values ,but I am getting confused on how can I set these values to MaxDate and MinDate of the Date Picker,because the returned response is not same always and may change later,I mean later start day of the week ,end day of the week may change,so how shall I implement it so that it will be efficient..please help me friends..I tried some code which is below,but I am not sure whether i am on the right path,so please show me direction and help me out

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

[Gregorian setfirstDayofWeek:2];
NSDateComponents  * comps =[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[comps setday:7];
```

Comment: ok nekto please help me out..

Comment: How do u parse daa from xml? In what format do u have it?

Comment: i have it in string format..i have taken all the data into the array

Comment: Hey Nikto string is same as above in my question..Hey nekto I habe one more doubt,I want to set the time range such that the user can select only those timings,suppose from 16:00 to 19:00,so the user cant select any other timings,how can i achieve that

Comment: I think, you should make 2 pickers. In one picker you can set only 2 dates. Moreover, may be it will be easier if you will make your custom picker?

Comment: Hey Nekto I have two diffrent pickers only..one for Date and One for Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I suggest you to create two `UIDatePicker`'s or one custom `UIDatePicker`.

If you will select first approach, you can set ranges of time in `UIDatePicker` in following way:

**Using IB:**

1. Select your `Date picker`.
2. Open `Utilities -> Attribute inspector`
3. In block `Constraints` :
4. Select `Minimum Date` and set its value `01/01/1970 16:00:00`
5. Select `Maximum Date` and set its value `01/01/1970 19:00:00`
6. Set value `Date` to `01/01/1970 16:00:00`