# how to set the date picker to display the year between 1910-2010 alone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uidatepicker

I am trying to show the date picker between 1910-2010 alone. i mean the user has to select between 1910 - 2010 only. i tried the below code but it is not working.

Also the date can be selected from 1 to 31st and month also can be selected from jan to dec.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [comps setYear:-3];
        NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:0 options:0];
        [comps setYear:1];
        NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:0 options:0];

    [self.myPicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
    [self.myPicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

Please let me know, what i am doing wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *minDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"1910-01-01"];
NSDate *maxDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2010-12-31"];
self. myPicker.minimumDate = minDate;
self. myPicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on these links,

[how to set MaxDate and MinDate to DatePicker returned from webservice on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559286/how-to-set-maxdate-and-mindate-to-datepicker-returned-from-webservice-on-ios)

[How to set Time Range in UIDatePickerModeTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568284/how-to-set-time-range-in-uidatepickermodetime)

[showing datepicker 18 years back and lock the ui datepicker in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853795/showing-datepicker-18-years-back-and-lock-the-ui-datepicker-in-ios)

hope it may helps you...